# How to implement pick button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm creating UI for my application and i need to know how to implement pick button for IOS.

I have one row in my interface (height=44) for this purpose. So i think to create button and push segue to table with list of options. 
When user taps button -> select option -> back to main view`, s/he must see selected option near the button (like table cell with details).

I don't know how to create custom button with 2 titles or something like this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you do is subclass `UITableViewCell` and create a new cell with the button on the left and a `UILabel` for the select option. Then use that custom cell in your UITableView instead of the standard UiTableViewCell. When user taps button - take them to the options screen. Save their selection so that when you return to the main view, you can reload the UITableView with the selected option set.

Comment: I need all orange rectangle to be a button. I tried to place on my view UITableViewCell without UITableView but it didn't work(not clcickable). Also i tried place that cell in UITableView with "Static Cells" option but this also didn't work on UIViewController.

Comment: UITableViewCell should never be used outside of UITableView. If this is the only row in your tableView - consider a different UI design.

Comment: Yes, this is only one row in my table! I also think to not use UITableView for this scenario. I don't know common way to do this easy task on IOS. I think that i need to create custom control but i don't know how?

Comment: Create a UIView (44 height by 320 width. ) Make it orange. Then put a add UiLabels and UiImages so it looks like the above. Then add a UIButton to the UIView - make it clear without a title and connect it so it take you to the next screen. Then, when user selects option - just update the UILabel in the UIView.

Comment: Yes. This is very helpful solution! I did it. Thank you!